# Retrieving equivalence values

Tags: r

I'm trying to gather values of `Magnitude` from one `dataframe` equivalent to those in another relative to their respective years, as a **Minimum**, so the larger dataset should have values greater than and equal to the equivalence values.

Here's a visual example of the original dataset, and my expectations:
[image]

The **Red-dot** represents the `MC_year` values, hence all values before it should be **cut-off**, and every values after the **peak** should be kept. However, each year has different **peak** values, so I'm trying to remove those values below the peak relative to each year. Hence, the new lowest **Magnitude** for each year, should have the highest **n** value.

I have tried:

```
base::intersect(l1.l1[l1.l1$Magnitude %in% MC_year$Magnitude,], l1.l1)
```

though I get this error:

> Error: Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector.
> i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
> x Input has size 2490 but subscript `!duplicated(x, fromLast = fromLast, ...)` has size 0.

**I have also tried:**

```
> subset(l1.l1, Magnitude >= MC_year$Magnitude) %>% arrange(Year)
```

Though, this is not relative to each year, as I'm missing lower magnitudinal values where `n` is largest.

Expectation:

```
 Magnitude  Year     n
       <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1       0.4  1987     50
 2       0.6  1987     15
 3       0.7  1987     2
 1       0.2  1988     80
 2       0.3  1988     20
 3       0.7  1988      5
```

Above expectation does not represent the reproducible code below, though its the expectation of the larger dataset I have. **Minimum** values should have the largest **n** count.

Reproducible example of `l1.l1` and `MC_year`:

```
l1.l1 <- structure(list(Magnitude = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4), 
    Year = c(1990, 1991, 1996, 2002, 2007, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
    2018, 1988, 1990, 1991, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 2002, 2003, 
    2004, 2005, 2007, 2009, 2010, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
    2020, 2021, 1990, 1991, 1994, 1995, 1996, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
    2005, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2010, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 
    2019, 2020, 2021, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 
    1995, 1996, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2015, 
    2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 1987, 1989, 1990, 1991, 
    1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
    2005, 2009, 2010, 2012, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
    2020, 2021), n = c(4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    15L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 31L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 22L, 7L, 7L, 
    11L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 24L, 19L, 14L, 16L, 
    5L, 1L, 1L, 58L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 7L, 41L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 11L, 38L, 31L, 35L, 21L, 33L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 92L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 12L, 16L, 73L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 10L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 27L, 59L, 66L, 44L, 47L, 42L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), groups = structure(list(Year = c(1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 
1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2012, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021), .rows = structure(list(75L, c(10L, 52L
), c(53L, 76L), c(1L, 11L, 31L, 54L, 77L), c(2L, 12L, 32L, 55L, 
78L), c(56L, 79L), c(13L, 57L, 80L), c(14L, 33L, 58L, 81L), c(15L, 
34L, 59L, 82L), c(3L, 16L, 35L, 60L, 83L), 84L, c(61L, 85L), 
    c(4L, 17L, 36L, 62L, 86L), c(18L, 37L, 63L, 87L), c(19L, 
    38L, 64L, 88L), c(20L, 39L, 89L), 40L, c(5L, 21L, 41L), 65L, 
    c(22L, 42L, 66L, 90L), c(23L, 43L, 67L, 91L), 92L, c(44L, 
    93L), c(6L, 24L, 45L, 68L, 94L), c(7L, 25L, 46L, 69L, 95L
    ), c(8L, 26L, 47L, 70L, 96L), c(9L, 27L, 48L, 71L, 97L), 
    c(28L, 49L, 72L, 98L), c(29L, 50L, 73L, 99L), c(30L, 51L, 
    74L, 100L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

MC_year <- structure(list(Magnitude = c(0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.1, 
0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.4), Year = c(1987, 1988, 1988, 1989, 1989, 
1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 
2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2010, 
2010, 2012, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2021
), n = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 92L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 12L, 16L, 73L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 10L, 11L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 27L, 59L, 66L, 44L, 47L, 42L, 8L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-38L), groups = structure(list(Year = c(1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 
1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2012, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2:3, 4:5, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14:15, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
    19L, 20L, 21:23, 24L, 25:26, 27:28, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
    34L, 35L, 36L, 37:38), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Expectation relative to example above**:

```
# Groups:   Year [30]
Magnitude  Year     n
<dbl> <dbl> <int>
1       0.4  1987     1
2       0.1  1988     1
3       0.3  1988     1
4       0.3  1989     1
5       0.4  1989     1
10      0.4  1990    92
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Comment: Can you share first few rows of expected output for the data shared?

Comment: @RonakShah The data shared, most values relative to magnitude are unique because the original dataset is very large! Though, I managed to find a year with a few values other than unique. Have a look! You'll notice that the minimum magnitude values are in `MC_year`, which should be in `l1.l1`, also, those minimum values have the largest `n` size, although, `l1.l1` should retain all values greater than the minimum.

Comment: You are intersecting a subset of `l1.l1` with `l1.l1`. The result should be that subset.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I think they're asking for the unique values from one dataset to be minimum values in the other, in respect to Year. Which is fairly clear from both examples.

Comment: It seems that `MC_year` is equivalent to `l1.l1 %>% slice_max(n)`, so you want those values of `Magnitude` less than the function mentioned, removed, and keep only those greater than and equal to, relative to their respective years?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the minimum of `Magnitude` for `l1.l1` from `MC_year` relative to `Year` up until `1992`, from `1993` the code fails. Though, this may help you or someone find a solution.:

```
p <- subset(l1.l1, Magnitude &  any(MC_year$n) & match(l1.l1$n, MC_year$n) )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 62 x 3
# Groups:   Year [30]
   Magnitude  Year     n
       <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1       0.4  1987     1
 2       0.1  1988     1
 3       0.3  1988     1
 4       0.3  1989     1
 5       0.4  1989     1
 6       0.4  1990    92
 7       0.1  1991     3
 8       0.2  1991     2
 9       0.3  1991     2
10       0.4  1991     2
# ... with 52 more rows
```